# What will effect the compling result of gcc?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I'm using a tool "EA" (Electric Accelerator) to speedup the compiling of my project.  I found that the compiling result of a C source file  by using EA and not using EA is different(on the same machine, distributed compiling is disable).  The compiling options passed to GCC are the same.  And, this only happens when "-O2" is used.  If I use "-O1" to compile the file,  the obj files are the same.  By analysing the assembly code, I found the code generated by using EA is correct too.  Obviously,   EA effects the compiling result of gcc.  How to explain this?

Comment: Maybe it internally changes the source file before it passes it to gcc (for optimization reason)? Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not precise on what you mean by compiling output? If you mean the assembly code generated. It will differ from compiler to compiler with respect to the level of optimization (namely `-O1 -O2`). That would be why you are getting different codes. I think it depends on how the compiler is tuned to optimize . [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) might help you.

Comment: I mean the obj files (.o) generated by gcc are different. Then I use objdump to disassemble the obj file, finding some assembly codes are different.  With or without EA, I always passed the same compiling options.  This problem only happens when "-O2" is used. Thanks.

Comment: When using `-O2`the compiler is notified to optimize. and compiler optimization uses code rearrangement , loop unrolling etc as methods to do it. So all these, you can expect the code to look different from how you wrote it because the compiler basically takes your code and rearranges it for better efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but with EA there is one factor that can produce different object files...

The tools and libraries on the agent machines that are used for the build have to be **exactly** the same as on the build machine if you want the .o's (or any other derived objects) to look the same. Remember that eMake feeds the commands in a recipe for a target in the makefile to a remote agent, and if the versions of the compiler, libraries, etc. are not the same as on the build machine, the result of the accelerated build will differ from a build run without acceleration.